# How to strip TCP headers from tcpdump (with hexadecimal output of non-printable data)

Tags: unix, tcpdump

`tcpdump` don't know how to strip TCP headers from packed data.

`tcpflow` print's only packet data, nice, but it supports only ASCII characters, no hexadecimal output possible.

Did I overlooked some option? Are there any other methods?

Comment: Maybe an awk/sed singleline?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible: tcpdump don't know how to print protocol-specific (eg: HTTP) data only.

Comment: Bad answer, the OP didn't want protocol-specific data, he wanted only the tcp stream.

Comment: Not true. He stated: "tcpdump don't know how to strip TCP headers from packed data". Note the "TCP headers" part. Anyway, if TCP headers are OK, he can simply use `tcpdump -X`